Apply an Event Label Filter to the Product Revenue metric in GBQ using Universal GA Data in Looker
I've got an event cat/action/label filter for my Authenticated vs Non-Authenticated users (written into the data layer and working in Universal Analytics) and I am trying to apply it to the product revenue metric in Looker using the GBQ data set. Applying the filter in looker returns "no data" which I first thought was a scope issue but after playing around I found that totals.totalTransactionRevenue will attach to the filter and return results. The first problem is that I want product revenue not transaction revenue but I can live with that if I have to. The second problem is when I apply the event label filter, the transaction revenue goes UP!? Am I missing something?
I've tried writing calculated metrics using item price X quantity to create a mock Product Revenue and that didn't work. I've got to be missing something with GBQ.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
